# Opening a file on a network share path with std::fstream in c++

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, fstream, shared-directory

In my app, written mostly in Qt, file I/O on windows network path such as `\\network\share\file.txt` work well for both reading and writing.

Except for opening EXR files, which are read through OpenEXR library, passing the file path as a `const char *`

After looking into OpenEXR source, it just passes the file path to the constructor of a std::ifstream. So it seems that Qt fully supports windows network paths, while MinGW stdlib  implementation does not.

Is the only solution to make a fstream wrapper class operating on a QFile, or am I missing something, such as slash encoding in path or anything else?

The path is obtained from a GUI open file dialog, and opens flawlessly with QFile.

Comment: The paths are always passed to the filesystem so there should be literally no difference. Time to show a testcase. You probably failed to escape something.

Comment: My magic wand shows that you have problem at line number 1339, my child!